Continuity of this function and well definedness
Consider $f: (0, 2] \to [-5, 7]$ defined as $f(x) = \begin{cases} x & 0 < x\leq 1 \\ 1 & 1 < x \leq 2 \end{cases}$
Is this function well defined? Is it continuous?
Attempts
I believe $f$ is well defined, since the domain is well specified and the codomain is $[-5, 7]$. It suffices that $x \in [-5, 7]$ then. Is that enough?
For the continuity part, it's not specified but I think it was understood "at $x = 1$".
I tried to used the definition the professor gave us, but I don't know if it's correct:
$$|f(x) - f(1)| = |x-1| \to 0\ \text{as}\ x\to 1$$
It looks too easy, so it will be surely wrong.
I did not use the right-left limits, because I wanted to avoid this technique.

It is true yes and enough. Continuity is understood at point $x=1$ and must be studiesfrom right and left.

$|f(x) - f(1)| = |x - 1|$ is not true for $x > 1$.

@BenSteffan Ah, here is the catch... But at $x = 1$ is continuous anyway. I don't need to think of $x > 1$ because in that case $f(x) = 1$ and it's continuous (?)

@Heidegger "but at $x = 1$ is continuous anyway" that's precisely what you're supposed to show! You absolutely need to think both of $x > 1$ and $x < 1$ and show that the limit approaching 1 from both sides is well defined and agrees with the other. No avoiding left-right limits here; this is precisely the technique you need to use (I recommend carefully rereading what it means for a function to be continuous at a point if any of this is not clear to you).

@BenSteffan With left and right limits I can do it! But I wanted to avoid them and try to use sequences instead. But it's still unclear to me on how to proceed

@Heidegger sequences and limits are the same thing, in a sense. Showing that $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = y$ is the same as showing that for all sequences $(x_n)$ converging to (but not attaining) $y$ you have $g(x_n) \to y$ as $n \to \infty$. In any case, open your textbook or lecture notes or similar, find the definition of continuous function or another characterization of continuity, and then try and show that that definition/criterion is satisfied for your $f$ in every point (and think about why only the point $x = 1$ really poses a potential issue).

@BenSteffan Could this work? I choose $b_n = 1+1/n$. Then I have to show that
$$f(1) = \lim_{n\to +\infty} f(b_n) \implies 1 = \lim_{n\to +\infty} 1 + 1/n$$
Which holds

@Heidegger To reemphasize: "Showing that $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = y$ is the same as showing that for all sequences $(x_n)$ converging to (but not attaining) $a$ [...]". You cannot just pick a single sequence and call it a day.

@BenSteffan Indeed, I was going to ask: "how could I be sure that this works for ALL the sequences that satisfy the required properties, that is $b_n \to 1$ at $n\to +\infty$ and $b_n \neq 1$. Well, I believe I will search for notes and learn!

I guess sequential criteria for continuity is usually used for proof by contradiction, because you cannot actually include your proof with all sequences (in fact if you can, then usually the functions are very easy because your arguments need to include ALL sequences, so the proof must be very general in the sense that it does not use any other property other than $a_n\to 1$. But if a general proof work, this means the function should be easy like $f(x)=x$.)

@Heidegger could you please edit the question. It is $f(x) \in [-5,7]$ and not $x \in [-5,7]$ in the attempts section.

Here is a graph for your piecewise function.


Continuous function: A function ($f$) whose left hand limit, right hand limit and the value of the function at any $c$ in the domain of $f$ is the same. In other words $lim_{x\to c}f(x) = f(c)$. If the domain of $f$ has specific intervals, then the continuity must be checked including the end points. Let the domain of $f$ is $[a,b]$. To determine whether $f$ is continuous at $a$, one must check if $lim_{x \to a^{+}}f(x) = f(a)$. On the other hand, to determine the continuity at $b$, one must check if $lim_{x \to b^{-}}f(x) = f(b)$ satisfies.

For our question,  the domain is of the form $(a,b]$. So, the function will be called as a continuous function if it is continuous over $(a,b)$ and is continuous from the left at $b$.

Let a point $x \in (0,2]$ or domain of the function. For all points $\in (0,2)$, the function is continuous. What about the continuity at $x = 2$? By definition, we additionally have to check if  $lim_{x \to 2^{-}}f(x) = f(2)$. This is definetely true.

Hence, the function is continuous.

Function: In our function, do we have multiple outputs for the same input?. Definetely not. So, our function can be called as a function in the first place. In our function, the co-domain is $[-5,7]$ while the range is $(0,1]$. Here, the $range \neq codomain$. Hence, the function is an into function, and not an onto function.

Well-defined function: Let us take $f(a/b) = a + b$. Let us test for $f(1/2)$ and $f(2/4)$. Even though the inputs are the same, the outputs are not the same. This means that the function is not well-defined, or ambiguous. In other words, a function is well-defined if it gives the same result when the representation of the input is changed without changing the value of the input. But, for our function, there is no such ambiguity.

Hence, the given function is well-defined.
